# a website that is blocked from being embedded in an iFrame. I need a legal workaround that allows me to post my store on my website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I need to add a website that is blocked from being embedded in an iframe. I need a legal workaround that allows me to post my store on my website. I'm not trying to hack anybody. Just want to safely and legally bypass this restriction. Thanks. :)
As it is not working kindly give me a solution or solve it and sent me the code will be appreciated thanks alot

[image: THIS IS HOW AFTER LOADING IT ON CHROME LOOKS]
[image: THIS IS ERROR]
[image]

```html
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">

  <html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>NextierAffiliate.com</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      <!-- html {
        height: 100% !important;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
      }
      
      td img {
        display: block;
      }
      
      body {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
      }
      
      #apDiv1 {
        POSITION: fixed;
        WIDTH: 292px;
        BOTTOM: -22px;
        DISPLAY: block;
        HEIGHT: 222px;
        VISIBILITY: visible;
        RIGHT: 145px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      
      -->
    </style>

    <script language="javascript">
      function DoClose() { <!-- Close the Popup
        document.getElementById('apDiv1').style.visibility = "hidden";
        return false;
      }
    </SCRIPT>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
      function MM_reloadPage(init) { //reloads the window if Nav4 resized
        if (init == true) with(navigator) {
          if ((appName == "Netscape") && (parseInt(appVersion) == 4)) {
            document.MM_pgW = innerWidth;
            document.MM_pgH = innerHeight;
            onresize = MM_reloadPage;
          }
        }
        else if (innerWidth != document.MM_pgW || innerHeight != document.MM_pgH) location.reload();
      }
      MM_reloadPage(true);
      //-->
    </script>



  </head>

  <body>

    <iframe id="iframe" src="<%= Session(" goURL ") %>" style="margin:0; width:100%; height: 100%; border:none; " cellpadding="0"></iframe>

    <div id="apDiv1">

      <table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td><img src="<%= Session(" naPopupImage ") %>" width=4 00; height=1 93; alt="" usemap="#mfmLink" border="0" />
            <map name="mfmLink" id="mfmLink"><area shape="rect" coords="367,4,391,26" onmouseover=" this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick= "DoClose()"  />
          <area shape="rect" coords="5,29,394,217" href="http://www.nextieraffiliate.com" target="_blank" />
      </map></td>
        </tr>
      </table>


  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by legally (it's opposite is illegally), but if both are websites you control, what's the issue?

Comment: check the question again plz..i have provided screen shots

Comment: The data i am fetching and trying to display it is not working idk why

Comment: The error in your screen shot tells you why. File not found and not allowed to load local resource. Are you just pulling up your site in the browser from the filesystem as opposed to having a server installed to get at it via localhost?

Comment: Ahh if you read the code i am fetching Map and i have to show the map in i frame

Comment: if you check the picture again i have posted at end its informing that the session is blocked

Comment: So you just ignore the 3 errors in the console then ask for help about this "block" you keep on insisting on?

Comment: Ah I am sorry but can you fix this?

Comment: Your question got closed already. You can attempt to start a new question and when someone helpful comes along in comments to assist you, you could try to be open to it next time. Presently, there's no way to post an answer here. Personally I dont think your question has to do with "SAMEORIGIN HTTP" but rather you have no JSP server active or you are not using it, hence `<%=` has the undesired effect.